# Missing org.javabuilders.event package in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I recently took over a Java Maven project that has been in the works for a couple of years. I am trying to clean up the project and make it easy to set-up for new developers and I am having trouble building one of the many modules. This module spit out the following error:

```
[Error] cannot find symbol
[Error] symbol: class IBindingListener
location: package org.javabuilders.event
```

This is my pom file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
        <version>5.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..\project-parent\pom.xml</relativePath>
      </parent>
      <groupId>com.company.project.net</groupId>
      <artifactId>asset-builder</artifactId>
      <name>Asset Builder Project</name>
      <description>This application will be used to design new asset types and modify existing asset types.</description>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
              <programs>
                <program>
                  <mainClass>com.company.project.assetbuilder.AssetBuilder</mainClass>
                  <name>assetbuilder</name>
                </program>
              </programs>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency> 
          <groupId>net.java.dev.glazedlists</groupId> 
          <artifactId>glazedlists_java15</artifactId> 
          <version>1.9.1</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kenai.swingjavabuilderext</groupId>
        <artifactId>javabuilder-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.3</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency> 
          <groupId>org.javabuilders</groupId> 
          <artifactId>javabuilder-swing-glazedlists</artifactId> 
          <version>1.0.1</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
          <type>jar</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
          <artifactId>asset-model</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
          <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.prefuse</groupId>
          <artifactId>prefuse</artifactId>
          <version>2007.10.21_e</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.company.aehf</groupId>
          <artifactId>aehf-cvra</artifactId>
          <type>jar</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
         <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
         <type>jar</type>
         <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.company.project.plugin</groupId>
          <artifactId>map-esri</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <type>jar</type>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>project-gui</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>project-model</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>network-calculation</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>jide-jdaf</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>jide-common</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kenai.swingjavabuilderext</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingjavabuilderext-jide-com</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
          <artifactId>asset-ose</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
          <artifactId>project-resources</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jide-components</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jide-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jide-charts</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jide-grids</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <reporting>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <suppressionsLocation>${basedir}/src/checkstyle/suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </reporting>
    </project>
```

Does anyone know where I can find this package or a package that contains the same class? I have looked on search.maven.org and all over the internet, but cannot find anything that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the package I was looking for. A previous employee who worked on the project had a Nexus repo containing the package. As far as I understand it is a very old package that is not really used anymore. That is why it is not easily found online.

Thanks for the help everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency to your pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kenai.swingjavabuilderext/javabuilder-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kenai.swingjavabuilderext</groupId>
    <artifactId>javabuilder-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have tried this to no luck. It still complains about the IBindingListener.

Comment: @BlueMoose you have added it to the classpath?Can you add the pom.xml to your question?

Comment: I added the class path to no luck. To make sure I added it right what should it look like? I added the pom file.